# Возврат к исходному DataContext после его смены на другой

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите пожалуйста.
Суть проблемы, у окна XAML задан
DataContext = new ViewModelMain();
В процессе работы его сменили на другой

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:SubGroupsTree}">
  <Expander>
    <StackPanel>
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Devices[0].Categories}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CategorySelectedCommand}" />
          </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
      </ListView>
      <Button Content="TEST"
      Command="{Binding CategorySelectedCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </Expander>
</DataTemplate>
```

У ListView в этом случае отрабатывает тот контекст, который и нужен. Но у i:InvokeCommandAction и у Button нужно что бы отрабатывал исходный дата контекст окна.
Возможно ли как-то этого добиться?
Для теста сделал команду CategorySelectedCommand у вторичного контекста, и сейчас срабатывает она, а не команда из основного контекста.

Comment: А смысл менять контекст? Мне кажется, если вы меняете контекст, значит вы делаете что-то не то, ибо он обычно статичен, задается раз, при создании объекта (обычно автоматически, самим WPF). Что касается привязки - обычно это делается при помощи поиска предка, например, через RelativeSource.

Comment: Хороший вопрос, который наводит на мысль, что проект требует рефакторинга. Но всё же хотелось бы понять, это невозможно в принципе и не стоит биться, или же всё же как-то возможно?

Comment: Возможно что? Сменить контекст и часть разметки привязать к другому? Ну напишите части разметки другой контекст, условно `<Grid><TextBox DataContext = "..." Text = "{Binding}"><StackPanel DataContext = "..."><TextBlock Text = "{Binding}"/></StackPanel></Grid>`. Ну а если вы задаете всему окну, то ок, пример `someClass.Value = 100; someClass.Value = 200;`, у вас `100` остается? Нет, если вы только сами это старое значение куда-то не сохранили, контекст это все тож самое свойство, которое тем-же самым правилам следует, изменили, нужно старое, сохраните его перед сменой куда-то и используйте.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ старое свойство остаётся. По выходу из блока DataTemplate я опять могу пользоваться им и там всё нормально отрабатывает. Сложность в том, что у меня не получается заставить у Button и i:InvokeCommandAction вызывать команду которая есть в основном контексте окна. Пробовал гуглить, спрашивал у нейронки, ни один вариант не подошёл. Что конкретно нужно указать в DataContext или блок Binding, что бы произошло обращение к команде из основного контекста?

Comment: Вот это `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:SubGroupsTree}">` я так понимаю переключает всё на класс **SubGroupsTree** и можно дёргать его команды.  По выходу из этого блока, всё возвращается обратно. Но у меня проблема в том, что нужно внутри этого блока дёрнуть методы основного контекста объявленного в Code Behind окна.

Comment: Я вам уже все нужное сказал еще в первом сообщении) Ищите предка через `RelativeSource` (мод `FindAncestor`), и уже к его свойствам привязывайтесь.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, да, спасибо, через предка удалось решить данную задачу.